# ZipArchive Error With INI Activation

Tags: php, dll

I'm trying to upload and extract a zip file on my localhost but I'm getting `Fatal error: Class 'ZipArchive' not found in C:\`

I've enabled `php_zip.dll` and also installed and enabled `zip.so` but still not able to run the Zip function. Any Ideas how to solve?

```
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_zip.dll
extension=zip.so
```

Comment: I know for a few of my .dll files, I had to provide the full path. "C:\PHP56\PHP56\ext\example.dll"

Comment: if you are on windows, DLL only, no .SO

Comment: @Eric - I tried only DLL and that didn't work so I added SO and still getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: @P.Gearman I've tried that but it's still giving the error

Comment: Hrm. The only other thing I can think of is how, back when I was using XAMPP, I somehow created a duplicate folder structure, and ended up with XAMPP working with the .ini file in one place, and me thinking it was somewhere else, so I was updating the wrong .ini file when I would manually update it.

Comment: @P.Gearman Yeah I thought about that but this is the file that it says in my phpinfo file. Is there any way of uploading multiple images through a single input field, creating a folder via php and then dropping the images into that folder?

Comment: This is probably an extremely dumb question, but you have checked that you actually have that php_zip.dll, right? I just looked at my previous installation of PHP 5.6, and it doesn't have it, so I thought I'd ask. (I did have to install it when I moved to a virtual box.)

Comment: @P.Gearman Yeah it's iin there. Going to try a different approach I think!